# Thycotic require execute twice the command to get the token using curl when MFA is active

Tags: bash, api, curl

I have the next code to get the Thycotic token in the file **GetToken.sh**.

This code defines a function called get_token, this function accepts 3 mandatory parameters USER_NAME, PASSWORD, and MFA_TOKEN. The function makes a Curl request using this information, saves the response into a txt file, and HTTP response into a variable.

But I need to execute twice the command using the same MFA Code to get the Auth token.

```
#!/bin/bash
export THYCOTIC_URL="https://mythycoticserver.com"
export TOKEN_PATH="/oauth2/token"
export CONTENT_TYPE_XWWWFORM="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"


function get_current_date {
  date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S%N
}


function get_token {
    local USER_NAME="${1}"
    local PASSWORD="${2}"
    local MFA_TOKEN="${3}"
    local DOMAIN="${4:-ANY}"
    local GRANT_TYPE="${5:-password}"

    REST_COMMAND=(--header "Content-Type:${CONTENT_TYPE_XWWWFORM}")

    if [[ -n "${MFA_TOKEN}" ]]; then
      REST_COMMAND+=(--header "OTP:${MFA_TOKEN}")
    fi

    if [[ -n "${USER_NAME}" ]]; then
      REST_COMMAND+=(--data-urlencode "username=${USER_NAME}")
    fi

    if [[ -n "${PASSWORD}" ]]; then
      REST_COMMAND+=(--data-urlencode "password=${PASSWORD}")
    fi

    if [[ -n "${DOMAIN}" ]]; then
      REST_COMMAND+=(--data-urlencode "domain=${DOMAIN}")
    fi

    if [[ -n "${GRANT_TYPE}" ]]; then
      REST_COMMAND+=(--data-urlencode "grant_type=${GRANT_TYPE}")
    fi

    REST_COMMAND+=(--url "${THYCOTIC_URL}${TOKEN_PATH}")

    FILE_NAME="${TMP}/response_$(get_current_date).txt"

    HTTP_RESPONSE=$(curl --no-progress-meter --insecure -o "${FILE_NAME}" -w "%{http_code}" -X POST "${REST_COMMAND[@]}")
    STATUS_CODE="$?"
    echo "HTTP RESPONSE: ${HTTP_RESPONSE} - ${STATUS_CODE}"

    if [[ "${HTTP_RESPONSE}" -ne 200 ]]; then
        echo "Process failed with code ${STATUS_CODE}."
        cat "${FILE_NAME}"
    else
        cat "${FILE_NAME}"
    fi
}
```

This is the execution secuence:
[This is the execution secuence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExSIh.png)

Do you know if I missed some Curl parameters, or do I need to execute additional requests first to save the server cache?

I don't want to execute twice the command for getting the token.

I will appreciate your suggestions